# How to power down Cloudstack configured with XenServer Hypervisors

Tags: centos, cloud, xenserver, selinux, cloudstack

I have three XenServers(6.2) configured in a single pool. I also have a Cloudstack (CentOS 6.5) Management interface controlling them all. Everything is up and running but I can not figure out how to power them all down properly. There is no documentation for a proper method.

Last time I shutdown each hypervisor one by one and then then shutdown the cloudstack management, they would not work upon a fresh start up. I couldn't resolve the issue and had to restore an image that was pre running the cloudstack initial wizard. This is just a test environment.

I know private clouds aren't typically powered down but there must be a proper method to do so. The NFS storage is located on the Cloudstack management interface. There is no fancy virtual switching or anything like that. Any ideas or direction you can provide for this?

Also I can not remote to my VM consoles without changing SElinux to permissive (or shutting it down). I have to change this setting every time a VM is created on a host. Is there a config file I modify to keep this off. Or to allow the connection to the console?

UPDATE: We had a power outage and it required another restore. Our *console proxy* and *storage* vms would not boot up. They were stuck in the **starting** state. our *virtual router* was missing too.